# Pause and Resuming a JQuery.animated object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm having trouble in trying to pause and resume a JQuery.animated object, it pauses fine but once it resumes animation it resets the animation from its current position so it ends up moving past the spot where it was meant to stop.

Heres a jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HemUe/) to help explain it better.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour? Are you trying to reset it so that it resumes from the top - where it started?

Comment: @leonxki Sorry I should have mentioned, No i want it to continue on from the position it 'paused' at but only go as far as it was originally meant to.

Comment: I think it's coz ur window height changes, as the divs slide down, try and `console.log(windowHeight)` what u get from it, n u got a funny way to code, ur taking away the `chainability` from jquery shame on you :) lol joking about last bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

I was just using the [suggestions from @DarthJDG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866730/pause-and-resuming-a-jquery-animated-object/5867290#5867290), also added the element's height so it doesn't go below the window border.

http://jsfiddle.net/HemUe/2/

Comment: This is what i was trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using relative animation targets. As far as I can tell, the plugin only takes the time elapsed into account when restarting the animation, the properties remain the same.

So if you start a linear animation for 5 seconds to move an element +100px and pause the animation after 2 seconds, it has already moved 40px. When the animation resumes, it will start an animation to move +100px for 3 seconds, and the element ends up moving 140px in total.

The solution is to use absolute values when calling `$box.animate()`, converting relative values to absolute there and then if necessary. Instead of moving `"+="+windowHeight`, set it to `$box.position().top + windowHeight`.

You might want to report this bug/limitation to the plugin's developer, but as the plugin's version is only 0.1, he might be well aware.